# i'm facing an error of ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got class membersDto { }

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

here is my schema file

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {HydratedDocument} from 'mongoose'
export type MemberDocument=HydratedDocument<memberAddress>;
@Schema()
export class memberAddress{
    @Prop()
    memver_id:string
   
    @Prop()
    city_id:string
    @Prop()
    state_id:string

    @Prop()
    pincode:number
    @Prop()
    address:string
    }
export const memberAddressSchema= SchemaFactory.createForClass(memberAddress)
```

and still i'm confused where i'm stuck????
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got class membersDto {
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
```

and your class should extends Document

```
export class memberAddress extends Document
```

else it will be considered like a simple data object and Mongoose can only create schema for documents

Comment: okk done but got another error is Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')